# Monero comparison wiki states zcash is not "decentralized": why?

Tags: cryptocurrency-comparison, zcash, decentralization, dash

https://www.reddit.com/r/monero/wiki/comparison

The monero comparison wiki states zcash is not decentralized. Why? Also since it's a monero subreddit, it can be seen as biased toward monero. What are some comparisons to make dash or zcash bias over monero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The monero comparison wiki states zcash is not decentralized. Why?

The [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/monero/wiki/comparison) you posted in your question, if you scroll down the page, has a pretty thorough answer to the question.

Most common criticisms of Zcash are the "Trusted Setup" and the "Founders Reward".

Comment: what does "trusted setup" mean?

Comment: Again, it's covered in the linked article. 

"Zcash was launched by way of something called the "multi-party computation" – also known as a "trusted setup." "The public parameters (zk-SNARK providing and verifying keys)" for Zcash's launch were constructed in a ceremony spearheaded by six individuals... The ceremony used a multi-party computation protocol with the property that the resulting parameters are secure unless all of the participants were dishonest or compromised during the ceremony"